# Passing a selector name as a method parameter

Tags: objective-c, selector, nsinvocation

I'm writing a custom helper method that will get used a lot and return several buttons. Each button will of course have its own target selector when pressed, and I want to pass the selector as a parameter into this method so the returned button has the specified selector.

But I'm not sure how to pass a selector as a method parameter. Something like this:

```
-(returnedInstance)someMethod:(WhatClass?*)selectedFunction{

[SomeClassWithASelectorParameter method:whatever selector:@selector(selectedFunction)];

}
```

where `selectedFunction` is a parameter passed into the method.

I tried making `WhatClass?*` a NSString and also SEL but that resulted in:

**[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be nil**

Comment: use `SEL` to pass the selector. and remove `@selector(..)` just use `selectedFunction`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just pass a `SEL`? i.e. a selector. Like so:

```
-(returnedInstance)someMethod:(SEL)selectedFunction{
    [SomeClassWithASelectorParameter method:whatever selector:selectedFunction];
}
```

Alternatively, `NSSelectorFromString`:

```
-(returnedInstance)someMethod:(NSString*)selectedFunction{
    [SomeClassWithASelectorParameter method:whatever selector:NSSelectorFromString(selectedFunction)];
}
```

Comment: Hehe thanks :-). That's one of my favourite things about SO - racing others to the answer whilst maintaining a complete, concise answer.

Comment: as my question indicated, I tried using SEL with no luck; getting the error I posted.

Comment: @andrewx - Yes, but did you try what I've posted? Both should work. Notice there's no `@selector(...)` in either.

Comment: actually, looks like it was merely my syntax that was wrong. i'll test some more and come back in a bit!

Comment: @andrewx - Sounds entirely plausible given you were trying with `@selector(...)`. That's never going to be the right way to do it if you're passing in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `SEL`, and when you refer to it, you don't have to use `selector`:

```
-(returnedInstance)someMethod:(SEL)selectedFunction{

    [SomeClassWithASelectorParameter method:whatever selector:selectedFunction];

}
```